# converting a DIV to base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, base64

How do I convert items inside a DIV to base64? See [examle FIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YvQ5y/973/)

html:

```
<div id="img2b64"> <img src="http://indianapublicmedia.org/stateimpact/files/2013/01/apple-image-300x300.jpg"> <div><br />
```

jQuery:

```
$('#ss').click(function(event){
    var imageUrl = $('#img2b64').find('input[name=url]').val();
    console.log('imageUrl', imageUrl);
    convertImgToBase64(imageUrl, function(base64Img){
        $('.output')
            .find('textarea')
                .val(base64Img)
                .end()
            .find('a')
                .attr('href', base64Img)
                .text(base64Img)
                .end()
            .find('img')
                .attr('src', base64Img);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
});


function convertImgToBase64(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image;
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat || 'image/png');
        callback.call(this, dataURL);
        // Clean up
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

Comment: What is not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Raidri: thanks. I get `imafgeUrl undefined` and `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:`

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageUrl = $('#img2b64').find('input[name=url]').val();
```

There is no `<input name="url">` in your code so this is returning `undefined`. Perhaps you meant:

```
var imageUrl = $('#img2b64').find('img').prop("src");
```

However you'll find that this introduces its own error:

> Image from origin 'http://indianapublicmedia.org' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Meaning that you can't load that image into a Canvas because the target server does not support CORS. You'll either have to download that image to your own server first & load it into your canvas from there. Either that or enable CORS on `indianapublicmedia.org`

Answer (score 0):

To problem that I see directly is in your jQuery where you do:

```
var imageUrl = $('#img2b64').find('input[name=url]').val();
```

Probably the `console.log()` below that line doesn't give you any valid URL, that should ring a bell. So the line above the `console.log()` doesn't do it's job.

That's because you are looking for any `<input />` element (with `name` attribute = `"url"`) inside the DIV with ID "img2b64". Also you are getting the value of the element with `val()`. You probably wanted to do something differently there.

If you want to get all images inside the DIV, then you need to simply look for `img`. To get the `src` attribute, do `attr('src')`:

```
var imageUrl = $('#img2b64').find('img').attr('src');
```

If you want to add an additional check for images with non-data `src`, do:

```
var imageUrl = $('#img2b64').find('img:not([src^="data"])').attr('src');
```

I did not check if the rest of the code (e.g. `convertImgToBase64()` function) is correctly working. You should always specify in your question what does work and what doesn't to get the best answers on SE.

Comment: thanks. you're correct on that piece. But as provided in the fiddle that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I get this error: `Image from origin 'http://indianapublicmedia.org' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.`